# If in a triangle ABC, ∠B = 2∠C and the bisector of ∠B meets CA in D, then the ratio BD : DC would be equal to?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Options :

(a) AD : AC
(b) AB : AD
(c) AB : AC
(d) AC : AB

?
i think all options are wrong, correct answer should be 1:1 or AB : AC ?

Comment: $\overline{BD} = \overline{DC}$.

Comment: Since $BD$ bisects $\angle B$, $\angle DBC = \frac12\angle B = \angle ACB = \angle DCB$, so $\triangle BCD$ is an isosceles triangle with $BD=CD$.

Comment: That's right it's impossible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right. All options are wrong.

a) $AD=AC$ is impossible;

b) If $AB=AD$ then $\measuredangle ADB=\measuredangle C$, which is impossible and

c), d) If $AB=AC$ then $\measuredangle C=\measuredangle ABC$, which is impossible.